# label command: application destroyed error

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```
I have written a gui code in python which calculate the age however when i run the code it shows the error of label command: application is destroyed. Furthermore it only show a screen with blue background colrs there are no labels or button visible. Also there are two screen being appeared
can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed
```

import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
main_window=tkinter.Tk()

class My_Age_Calculator:
def **init**(self):
self.main_window= tkinter.Tk()
self.main_window.geometry('525x260')
self.main_window.title('Age Calculator')
self.main_window.configure(bg='light blue')

```
    ## Creating Labels
    # 1.Date of Birth
    DOB=tkinter.Label(main_window, text="Date Of Birth", bg='pink')
    
    #2. Given Date:
    given_date=tkinter.Label(main_window, text="Given Date", bg="pink")
    
    # 3. Day
    Day = tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Day", bg = "light blue")
    
    #4. Month
    Month =tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Month", bg = "light blue")
    
    #5.Year
    Year = tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Year", bg = "light blue")
    
    #6. Given Day
    Given_Day =tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Given Day", bg = "light blue")
    
    #7. Given Month
    Given_Month =tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Given Month", bg = "light blue")
    
    #8. Given Year
    Given_Year =tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Given Year", bg = "light blue")
    
    #9. Resultant Year
    Resultant_Year = tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Year", bg = "light blue")
    
    #10.Resultant_Month
    Resultant_month =tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Month", bg = "light blue")
    
    #11.Resultant_Day
    Resultant_day = tkinter.Label(main_window, text = "Day", bg = "light blue")
    
    
    ## Creating Resultant Age and Clear all button:
    #1 Resultant Age:
    Resultant_Age = tkinter.Button(main_window, text = "Resultant Age", fg = "Black", bg = "light green", command=Calculate_Age)
    
    #2. Clear All:
    Clear_All = tkinter.Button(main_window, text = "Clear All", fg = "Black", bg = "light green", command= Clear_All)
    
    ## Creating Entry box for entering the information
    
    #1 Date of Birth
    day_box =tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    month_box = tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    year_box =tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    
    #2 Given Date
 
    given_day_box = tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    given_month_box= tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    given_year_box = tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    
    #3. Resultant Age
    
    resultant_year_box = tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    resultant_month_box =tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    resultant_Day_box = tkinter.Entry(main_window)
    
    ## The widgets are placed in their position using grid method.
    #1. Date Of Birth
    
    
    DOB.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    Day.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    day_box.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
 
    Month.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    month_box.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
   
    Year.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    year_box.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    
    #2. Given Date
 
    given_date.grid(row = 0, column = 4)
 
    Given_Day.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    given_day_box.grid(row = 1, column = 4)
 
    Given_Month.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    given_month_box.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
 
    Given_Year.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    given_year_box.grid(row = 3, column = 4)
    
    #3. Resultant Age
 
    Resultant_Age.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
 
    Resultant_Year.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
    resultant_year_box.grid(row = 6, column = 2)
 
    Resultant_month.grid(row = 7, column = 2)
    resultant_month_box.grid(row = 8, column = 2)
 
    Resultant_day.grid(row = 9, column = 2)
    resultant_Day_box.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

    Clear_All.grid(row = 12, column = 2)
```

main_window.mainloop()
agecal_1=My_Age_Calculator()

```
Please help me in solving these errors
```

Comment: Please format the code.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: rephrase the error

> I have written a gui code in python which calculate the age however
> when i run the code it shows the error of label command: application
> is destroyed. Furthermore it only show a screen with blue background
> colrs there are no labels or button visible. Also there are two screen
> being appeared can't invoke "label" command: application has been
> destroyed.

**Noticed**, you cannot use `main_window=tkinter.Tk()`, because you already have `self.main_window= tkinter.Tk()` in instantiate class. So comment out on line 3.

On line 120, in my case, When I moved `main_window.mainloop()` inside `def __init` function. I made an error.

```
DOB=tkinter.Label(main_window, text="Date Of Birth", bg='pink')
NameError: name 'main_window' is not defined. Did you mean: 'self.main_window'?
```

So you will have to use `self` for every `tkinter` widgets.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
#main_window=tkinter.Tk()

class My_Age_Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window= tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.geometry('525x260')
        self.main_window.title('Age Calculator')
        self.main_window.configure(bg='light blue')
        
        ## Creating Labels
        # 1.Date of Birth
        DOB=tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text="Date Of Birth", bg='pink')
        
        #2. Given Date:
        given_date=tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text="Given Date", bg="pink")
        
        # 3. Day
        Day = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Day", bg = "light blue")
        
        #4. Month
        Month =tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Month", bg = "light blue")
        
        #5.Year
        Year = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Year", bg = "light blue")
        
        #6. Given Day
        Given_Day =tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Given Day", bg = "light blue")
        
        #7. Given Month
        Given_Month =tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Given Month", bg = "light blue")
        
        #8. Given Year
        Given_Year =tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Given Year", bg = "light blue")
        
        #9. Resultant Year
        Resultant_Year = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Year", bg = "light blue")
        
        #10.Resultant_Month
        Resultant_month =tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Month", bg = "light blue")
        
        #11.Resultant_Day
        Resultant_day = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text = "Day", bg = "light blue")
        
        
        ## Creating Resultant Age and Clear all button:
        #1 Resultant Age:
        Resultant_Age = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,
                                       text = "Resultant Age", fg = "Black",
                                       bg = "light green", command=My_Age_Calculator)
        
        #2. Clear All:
        Clear_All = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,
                                   text = "Clear All", fg = "Black", bg = "light green",
                                   )
        
        ## Creating Entry box for entering the information
        
        #1 Date of Birth
        day_box =tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        month_box = tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        year_box =tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        
        #2 Given Date
     
        given_day_box = tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        given_month_box= tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        given_year_box = tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        
        #3. Resultant Age
        
        resultant_year_box = tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        resultant_month_box =tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        resultant_Day_box = tkinter.Entry(self.main_window)
        
        ## The widgets are placed in their position using grid method.
        #1. Date Of Birth
        
        
        DOB.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        Day.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        day_box.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
     
        Month.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        month_box.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
       
        Year.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        year_box.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        
        #2. Given Date
     
        given_date.grid(row = 0, column = 4)
     
        Given_Day.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        given_day_box.grid(row = 1, column = 4)
     
        Given_Month.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        given_month_box.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
     
        Given_Year.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
        given_year_box.grid(row = 3, column = 4)
        
        #3. Resultant Age
     
        Resultant_Age.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
     
        Resultant_Year.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
        resultant_year_box.grid(row = 6, column = 2)
     
        Resultant_month.grid(row = 7, column = 2)
        resultant_month_box.grid(row = 8, column = 2)
     
        Resultant_day.grid(row = 9, column = 2)
        resultant_Day_box.grid(row = 10, column = 2)
 
        Clear_All.grid(row = 12, column = 2)
    
        
   
            
        self.main_window.mainloop()
agecal_1=My_Age_Calculator()
```

Result errors, so far there are no errors:

[image]

Comment: Which line number did you get this?  "can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed "

Comment: DOB=tkinter.Label(main_window, text="Date Of Birth", bg='pink')